# flex graph categoryAxis multiline labels not shown completely

Tags: apache-flex, graph, multiline, axis-labels

The same question is asked by others here:

http://www.amcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=39204#p39204

But not public and general solution is provided.

For example, my categoryAxis label is composed of day, month and year, which are supposed to be displayed in 3 lines.But sometimes when the chart is zoomed, 'year' may be missing.
Like the graphs shown here:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4817858#4817858

Anyone knows how to solve this  problem?

I tried to find properties of AxisRenderer that may be related to this but failed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: on that thread (your link) the answer is there.  It says you need to call invalidateMargins() after a zoom event occurs.